# Cleanly handling issues during class instantiation

Tags: python, class, error-handling, python-2.7

I'm writing a Python class that will be imported & used by multiple calling applications.  Each of the calling apps will be written such that it instantiates the class once (and once only) at startup, and then maintains that instance until the app is closed.

Successful instantiation involves a fairly long list of dependencies & checks, e.g. the presence of a given MS Access file in a given folder, the ability to update that DB, having read/write privs to a log file off in another folder, the presence of certain other folders in relation to the calling app... you get the idea.  What I want to do is check all these dependencies at class instantiation.  If any of them fail, code within the class would supply an error popup for the user, and then refrain from instantiating the class.  The calling app would then detect that the class wasn't instantiated and simply exit.

I've rooted through various other threads, and the options I've found are either creating a Factory (which seems kind of overblown for what's needed), or overriding the `__new__` method (which per other discussions can be tricky...pretty much every code sample I found had long train of comments warning of all the circumstances where it wouldn't work).

So from a preferred-practice standpoint, is either of these the way to go?  Or is there some other alternative that would be best for what I'm looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard practice is to raise an exception, with the code instantiating your class catching and handling that exception:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        if not self._database_exists(foo):
            raise ValueError('No valid database {}'.format(foo))

        # etc.
```

then:

```
try:
    theinstance = MyClass('foooption', barvalue, bazvalue)
except ValueError as e:
    # Oops, something went wrong
    showErrorToUser(e)
    theinstance = None
```

Comment: Thanks.  Even though this means a couple extra lines in the calling apps, it's much clearer as to what's going on than my original plan (class silently goes un-created).